# Navigate to new screen in persistent_bottom_nav_bar without Nav Bar

Tags: flutter, user-interface, navigation, navigationbar

I am using the [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package, and I want to navigate to my title page after I Sign Out of the account. The problem is that when using

```
pushNewScreen(
 context,
 screen: titlePage(),
 withNavBar: false,
);
```

I am able to Navigate to the Title page but when I press back button it goes back to my log out screen.

When using Navigator.pushReplacement() like this

```
 Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
       context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => titlePage(),
        ),
     );
```

I am able to get to the Title Page but the app bar is still showing in title page which I don't want.

How to navigate to the Title Page after popping out all the screens and Nav Bar hidden?

Answer (score 0):

if i completely understand your problem, you have to use ***pushAndRemoveUntil***
here is an exemple that worked for me :

```
void navigateAndFinish(context, widget) =>
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => widget,
  ),
  (route) => false,
);
```

and this how to use it

```
    navigateAndFinish(context,const HomeScreen());
```

Comment: Tried but the NavigationBar is still displaying in TitlePage.

Comment: On the exemple provided by the owner of the package you've used , there is something  called "popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true" did you tried it?

Comment: Nope, this didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Recently i made a custom persistent navigation bar without use of any packages and i uploaded code on my github account you can use it as per your need its is easy and understanable. Happy coding

[Check out now](https://github.com/Priyanshusoni/persistent_navigator)